# Linq Query : Cannot convert type IEnumerable<string> to string changing .ToString() to (string)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query that contains

```
select new Project()
           {                             
               Manager =  list.Employee.Select(x => x.Manager).ToString()
           }).ToList();
```

This COMPILES, but I don't end up with the data...
I get value for "Manager" of  `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator<Flex.Data.Systems,System.String>`
So I thought I would change to `(string)` instead of  `.ToString()`  but this does not work

```
select new Project()
           {                             
               Manager =  (string)list.Employee.Select(x => x.Manager)
           }).ToList();
```

Gives me the error message

> > Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'

**I need it to be a collection**, so that when I pass back out my `List<Project>` that `Manager` contains many Managers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What do you want `Manager` to be, a `string` with a comma separated list of values or a `List<string>`/`String[]`?

string:

```
Manager =  string.Join(",",list.Employee.Select(x => x.Manager))
```

collection:

```
Manager =   list.Employee.Select(x => x.Manager).ToList()
// or
Manager =   list.Employee.Select(x => x.Manager).ToArray()
```

Comment: I need it to be a collection, so that when I pass back out my List<Project> that Manager contains many Managers  ,  so the second part it what i need but Manager =   list.Employee.Select(x => x.Manager).ToList()  does not work as it gives me a Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'

Comment: @corestone: then you have to change the type of your property from string to List<string>.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `list.Employee.Select(x => x.Manager)` returns a collection of managers and property `Manager` is a string (?). You need some condition of which manager you want. For example append `.First()` to get the first one in the collection.

Comment: He hasn't meenioned that it's a `string` property, although it's very likely since he uses `ToString`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That is true, but I don't see any other reason for trying to cast it into a string.

Comment: I see, I can get that to at least give result, but I want to definitely pass back a collection.   So I don't really want to even map these directly as I'm realizing this "select new Project" is creating a single record and I just want to pass data into the Project List

Comment: @CoreStone Then you are going to have to change `Manager` in class `Project` from a string to a List<String> and append a `.ToList()` to your expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this worked for me :

```
 var returnCollection = (from manager in list.Employee 
     select manager).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make a selection of columns from a collection it will return a collection. Even if you specify a where clause to match an exact record.

For your case, you can have them converted to

```
Manager =   list.Employee.Select(x => x.Manager).ToList()
```

or

```
Manager =   list.Employee.Select(x => x.Manager).ToArray()
```

This is what Tim told above.

There could be case where you get a collection and you are sure that the first one is what you need. For that you can always use:

```
Manager =   list.Employee.Select(x => x.Manager).First();
```

**Note:** This might throw an error if there is nothing found as a collection along with where clause used. In such case use:

```
Manager =   list.Employee.Select(x => x.Manager).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will not give error even if noting is returned matching.